# Regular expression to flag more that n number of occurrances

Tags: regex, slack

I have a regex that compares the US Phone numbers and it works fine. Now , the requirement is to flag this only if there are 5 or more phone numbers in one line.

```
(?:\d{1}\s)?\(?(\d{3})\)?-?\s?(\d{3})-?\s?(\d{4})
```

(We want to implement this in Slack DLP rules. So we don't have option to programmatically count and use JavaScript or Python and loop through the results.). Following are some of the exptected match/no match results:

```
1 416 555 929 //no match

1 416 555 9294 this 1 416 555 9292 also 416 558 9297 asjdks 416-555-9298 alksdjfskfd 416555929 //match

1 416 555 9294 this 1 416 555 9292 also 416 558 9297 asjdks 416-555-9298 alksdjfskfd //no match
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the second line there are only 9 digits at the end which should be at least 10 digits according to the pattern.

To get that match, you can repeat your pattern 5 times and you can omit the capture groups for a match only:

```
(?:.*?(?:\d\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?-?\s?\d{3}-?\s?\d{4}){5}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rwezBV/1)